# Convert double for loop into list comprehension

Tags: python

I have the following json object:

```
{u'trailerAvailable': False, u'number': 10, u'watched': False, u'starringCast': u'Jan Fedder,Anja Nejarri', u'genres': [u'Krimi'], u'title': u'S\xfc\xdfes Jenseits', u'ancestorTitles': [{u'contentType': u'SERIES', u'titleId': u'B00ILY1FWE', u'title': u'Gro\xdfstadtrevier'}, {u'contentType': u'SEASON', u'number': 19, u'titleId': u'B00ILZTVXI', u'title': u'Gro\xdfstadtrevier - Staffel 19'}], u'restricted': False, u'synopsis': u"Dirk Matthies und Katja Metz erhalten einen entscheidenden Tipp, um endlich Hannes Rogolski alias 'die Ziege' zu fassen. Allerdings bringt der schwer kranke Informant dadurch seine Lebensgef\xe4hrtin Hilde in Gefahr.", u'titleId': u'B00ILZOQWE', u'watchCompleted': False, u'creditsStartTimeMillis': 2836000, u'customerReviewsCollectionIncluded': True, u'contentType': u'EPISODE', u'childTitles': [], u'studioOrNetwork': u'ARD', u'amazonRating': {u'count': 0, u'rating': 0.0}, u'watchedPositionMillis': {u'valueMillis': 0}, u'listInfo': [], u'previewAvailable': False, u'subtitles': {u'content': {u'languages': []}, u'preview': {u'languages': []}, u'trailer': {u'languages': []}}, u'restrictions': [], u'regulatoryRating': u'12', u'releaseOrFirstAiringDate': {u'valueFormatted': u'2005-03-21T00:00:00', u'valueDate': 1111363200000000}, u'hasSubtitles': False, u'formats': [{u'hasMobileTrailerEncode': False, u'videoAspectRatio': 0.0, u'offers': [{u'asin': u'B0043YVHMY', u'offerType': u'SUBSCRIPTION', u'buyable': False}, {u'asin': u'B00ILZOQWE', u'price': {u'valueFormatted': u'1,49\u20ac', u'valueLong': 149.0}, u'offerType': u'PURCHASE', u'purchaseButtonText': u'Buy episode - 1,49\u20ac', u'buyable': True}, {u'rentalExpiryTermFromPurchase': {u'valueMillis': 2592000000, u'valueFormatted': u'30 days to start watching'}, u'asin': u'B00QVECS4U', u'rentalExpiryTermFromStart': {u'valueMillis': 86400000, u'valueFormatted': u'24 hours to complete watching'}, u'offerType': u'RENTAL', u'buyable': False}], u'audioFormatTypes': [u'STEREO'], u'videoFormatType': u'SD', u'hasMobileEncode': True, u'images': [{u'heightPx': 0, u'widthPx': 0, u'type': u'COVER_ART_TV', u'uri': u'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51a8c53GcjL._UR667,500_V1_PJStripe-Prime-Only-500px,TopLeft,0,0_.jpg'}, {u'heightPx': 0, u'widthPx': 0, u'type': u'COVER_ART_TV', u'uri': u'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51a8c53GcjL._UR667,500_V1_PJStripe-Prime-Only-500px,TopLeft,0,0_.jpg'}], u'hasTrailerEncode': False, u'hasEncode': True}, {u'hasMobileTrailerEncode': False, u'videoAspectRatio': 0.0, u'offers': [{u'asin': u'B0043YVHMY', u'offerType': u'SUBSCRIPTION', u'buyable': False}, {u'asin': u'B00ILZOR9Q', u'offerType': u'PURCHASE', u'buyable': False}, {u'rentalExpiryTermFromPurchase': {u'valueMillis': 2592000000, u'valueFormatted': u'30 days to start watching'}, u'asin': u'B00QVFSN0W', u'rentalExpiryTermFromStart': {u'valueMillis': 86400000, u'valueFormatted': u'24 hours to complete watching'}, u'offerType': u'RENTAL', u'buyable': False}], u'audioFormatTypes': [u'STEREO'], u'videoFormatType': u'HD', u'hasMobileEncode': False, u'images': [{u'heightPx': 0, u'widthPx': 0, u'type': u'COVER_ART_TV', u'uri': u'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51a8c53GcjL._UR667,500_V1_PJStripe-Prime-Only-500px,TopLeft,0,0_.jpg'}, {u'heightPx': 0, u'widthPx': 0, u'type': u'COVER_ART_TV', u'uri': u'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51a8c53GcjL._UR667,500_V1_PJStripe-Prime-Only-500px,TopLeft,0,0_.jpg'}], u'hasTrailerEncode': False, u'hasEncode': False}], u'customerReviewCollection': {u'customerReviews': [], u'customerReviewSummary': {u'totalReviewCount': 0, u'threeStarReviewCount': 0, u'averageOverallRating': 0.0, u'twoStarReviewCount': 0, u'fiveStarReviewCount': 0, u'oneStarReviewCount': 0, u'fourStarReviewCount': 0}}, u'runtime': {u'valueMillis': 2820000, u'valueFormatted': u'47m'}, u'contractID': u'UXSG4'}
```

I am trying to get all the `asin`s by doing:

```
possible_episode_ids = []
for item in t['formats']:
    for i in item['offers']:
        possible_episode_ids.append(i['asin']) 

>>> possible_episode_ids
[u'B0043YVHMY', u'B00ILZOQWE', u'B00QVECS4U', u'B0043YVHMY', u'B00ILZOR9Q', u'B00QVFSN0W']
```

How would I do this with a list comprehension?

Comment: `[i['asin'] for i in title['offers'] for item in t['formats']]` but you never use `item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the existing lines:

```
possible_episode_ids = [
    i['asin']
    for item in t['formats']
    for i in item['offers']
]
```

Comment: I think you have that backwards.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You are correct, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
possible_episode_ids=[offer['asin']  for fmt in t['formats'] for offer in fmt['offers']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
possible_episode_ids = [j['asin'] for i in t['formats'] for j in i['offers']]
```